# Circular contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> Let $\gamma$ be the circular contour, positively oriented, with centre $0$ and radius $7$. Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be complex numbers. Compute the following integral
>   $$\int_{\gamma } \frac{A+Bz+Cz^2}{z^n} dz.$$

I have no clue where to start with this question if anybody could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Recall that the [residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)) at $0$ of a function $f$ is the coefficient of $1/z$ in the [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) expansion of $f$ centered at $0$. In this case, the given function is already expanded and  therefore, by the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem),
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=7 } \frac{A+Bz+Cz^2}{z^n} dz=\begin{cases}
A&\text{if $n=1$,}\\
?&\text{if $n=2$,}\\
?&\text{if $n=3$,}\\
0&\text{otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}$$
Are you able to complete the evaluation?

Comment: hey thanks but what do the question marks in the answer mean?

Comment: I gave you a hint. Are you able to complete the solution?

Comment: I dont think I would be able to Its just a bit confusing for me, I'm better at seeing the final solution and working backwards to understand something :/ I'm sorry.

Comment: On the right side, you have to determine the coefficient of $1/z$ of the given function.

Comment: I think I got it thank you would it be A if n=1 B if n=2 C if n=3

Comment: Yes, correct! So it was not so terrible... ;-) Note the result does not depend on the radius of the circle.

Comment: Thanks for the help honestly. Just 2 quick questions you have 1/2pi i in your workings but mine didn't I was wondering on were it came from and also would I just need to state the expansion of f centered 0 and equate them (as in where could I see that the residue at 0 is the coefficient of 1/z.

Comment: As regards $2\pi i$ see the link to the Residue Theorem above. For the second one see the definition of residue https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)

Comment: Thanks so much I really appreciate it

Comment: @RodgerS You are welcome!